# libsvm svmpredict method output model file

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I use libsvm svmpredict method for classifying the images on Matlab. 
I need svmpredict method's output model file that has extension with ".model". But I cannot create it. My usage is that,

```
model = svmtrain(train_label_set_libsvmformat, train_data_set_libsvmformat, '-t 2 -c 0.3 -g 0.01');
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = svmpredict(test_label_set_libsvmformat, test_data_set_libsvmformat, model, 'output.model');
```

I wait for creating this file "output.model", but it doesn't exist.
Is there anything that is wrong for me?

Comment: You need to give us more information: How do you execute libsvm? From C++, Java, command line, ...?

Comment: I use libsvm in matlab. I use svmtrain and svmpredict methods in matlab .m file. I use Matlab7.8.0(R2009a) and visaul 2008 c++ compiler.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/libsvm_matlab

```
% Train the SVM
model = svmtrain(trainLabel, trainData, '-c 1 -g 0.07 -b 1');
% Use the SVM model to classify the data
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = svmpredict(testLabel, testData, model, '-b 1'); % run the SVM model on the test data
```

The last argument of `svmpredict` is not a filename, but the options you want to pass to `svmpredict`. If you want to save a model to a file, this usually is done when training the model in `svmtrain`. If you use the command line version of `svm-train`, the model-file is an additional parameter.

From what I make of the source code of libsvm for MATLAB, the model you get from executing the `svmtrain` command is just a scalar in MATLAB, so there is no built-in way to obtain a model-file.

If you want a model-file, you have to use the command line version of libsvm.

Comment: "If you want a model-file, you have to use the command line version of libsvm." I cannot understand it. 
Also, I saw it on the readme file of libsvm.
svm-predict [options] test_file model_file output_file
I ask about this output_file. Can I save this output_file?

Comment: You are using libsvm for MATLAB. The readme you are referring to is for the command line. You know, when you open the command line, a terminal, a shell, and type `svm-predict -t 2 test.ft train.model output` or something.